# ngStyle background image not visible

Tags: angular, background, ng-style

I've got the following problem: I want to insert a background image to my website with ngStyle. The following code works fine:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + myBackgroundUrl + ')', 'width': '224px', 'height': '248px'}"></div>
```

However, if I want to add some more "attributes" to the background-image, the image isn't visible anymore:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + myBackgroundUrl + ') no-repeat -228px 0', 'width': '224px', 'height': '248px'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **background-image** property **sets one or more background images for an element**.

If you want to add some more "attributes" then use **background** instead:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{
  'background': 'url(' + myBackgroundUrl + ') no-repeat -228px 0', 
  'width': '224px', 
  'height': '248px'
}"></div>
```

Comment: @Felixbrandi You're welcome! Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helps. Thanks